# How to fix no more spool space in teradata?

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

My error is **no more spool space** when I create a table with the qualify number_rows, 
the goal is to get the first 100 samples by key, 
each key is composed by the following fields: (top_typ_vision, instid, don_gener3, don_gener4,rg_no, lieu_stkph_cd,id_sect_base_resp)

When I execute the select, the code works very well, once I add the create I get the error **no more spool space**

thank you !!

````
```sql
create multiset table mdc_cobalt_det as (
sel
top_typ_vision, 
instid, 
type_enr as type_obj_ofs,
don_gener1, 
don_gener2, 
don_gener3, 
don_gener4, 
rg_no,
lieu_stkph_cd,
id_sect_base_resp
from PROD_V_CTRL_ANOMALIE
qualify row_number () over (partition by top_typ_vision, 
instid, 
don_gener3, 
don_gener4,
rg_no, lieu_stkph_cd,
id_sect_base_resp order by rg_no ) <= 100)
with data 
primary index (top_typ_vision, rg_no, don_gener3, don_gener4, lieu_stkph_cd, id_sect_base_resp);
````

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to:

- Collect **statistics** on your input table and try to run it again;
- Create this mdc_cobalt_det  table as a NOPI table and check data distribution in fields chosen to be your primary index.